# .htacces This webpage has a redirect loop error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have problem with my .HTACCESS CODE

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
ErrorDocument 400 /notfound.php
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^download/([\d]+)?/(.+?)$ index.php?page=viewarticle&id=$1
RewriteRule ^category/([\d]+)?/(.+?)$ index.php?page=viewcat&catid=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I am getting error "This webpage has a redirect loop"
what to do?

Comment: Try removing the last two lines.. What then? And what do you want to accomplish with them?

Comment: its still the samething

Comment: You have to find the fault by removing lines and see. Is notfound.php actually present?

Answer (score 1):

This rule is causing the loop:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

It is essentially saying: If the requested host is "website.com" redirect it to "website.com"

You may be meaning something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

You'll also need to place this rule **before** all your other rules, because otherwise you'd be redirecting to `/index.php` instead of the nicer looking URL.